# How to Create an alias in Linux?

Tags: linux, command, alias

Let's say I want to create an alias for srm (safe remove), such that everytime srm is used, an interactive rm command runs, e.g. rm –i.  This change needs to be made to the necessary configuration files such that the alias is set every time any user logs in.   Also show that your alias works.

How would i go about doing this?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Edit your `~/.bashrc`, adding the following line to the bottom:

```
alias srm="rm -i"
```

Comment: you can use `doskey` command to set an alias if you are a windows user like this `doskey ls=dir` then running `ls` will run `dir` command