# How to use latest gstreamer to play a video file on ubuntu system?

Tags: gstreamer

When I use *gst-play-1.0* to play any video source on ubuntu system, what I could see is, it is using very old gstreamer version i.e. gst-launch-1.0, GStreamer 1.2.4 using function *gst_version (&major, &minor, &micro, &nano)*.

When I listed all installed gstreamer versions I observed that gstreamer-1.8.2 is also present.

So, my question is how to change or linked the latest version of gstreamer.

Comment: How did you list all installed GStreamer versions?

Comment: @Snec, I used *dpkg -l | grep gstreamer* which was suggested in one of the thread [http://askubuntu.com/questions/769413/how-do-i-check-gstreamer-version]

Comment: **GST_DEBUG=*:4**                                                                                      `GST_INIT gst.c:511:init_pre: Initializing GStreamer Core Library version 1.8.2`

Answer (score 0):

The title of this question is misleading, and the question is actually an operating system question rather than a gstreamer question.  Assuming you have a Linux OS you can create an alias.

[creating an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585918/creating-an-alias)

Comment: *Linux is just the environment*. I would like to correct my question  if it is not clear. The problem here is I have Mpeg-Dash test link which plays fine on my PC(ubuntu), which is using old gstreamer 1.2.4. However it doesn't play the same test link with Raspberry Pi which is using latest gstreamer 1.8.2.

Comment: I somewhat understand the premise of your revised question, but I can't recreate your work or possibly know what you are trying to do, so please show some work, code or command lines, gstreamer pipelines, etc. and for both environments.  Show us what is working and what is not.

Comment: here is the command line for both environments: `gst-play-1.0 "http://b028.wpc.azureedge.net/80B028/SampleStream/595d6b9a-d98e-4381-86a3-cb93664479c2/b722b983-af65-4bb3-950a-18dded2b7c9b.ism/Manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)"`